getBorderStyle() to setBorderStyle()
I am trying to use the .getBorderStyle() function from one cell and change the setting for another cell to the same border style. This will not work for me though. When I go to use the border style to set the border it is null. I have put two example of this below.
function borderpaste(range,destination) {
  var rangenr = range.getNumRows();
  var rangenc = range.getNumColumns();for(var i=0;i<rangenr;i++){
    for(var j=0;j<rangenc;j++){
    var sBD = range.offset(i,j).getBorder();
if(sBD!==null){
      var sBDR = sBD.getRight().getBorderStyle();
      if(sBDR!==null){
  destination.offset(i,j,1,1).setBorder(null,null,null,true,false,false,SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.sBDR)}
      console.log(SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.sBDRs);}
      }

I have tried also to put this into a string and then using the number but this does not work either. This probably does not work because this method is looking for an enum and not a string.
 function borderpaste(range,destination) {
  var rangenr = range.getNumRows();
  var rangenc = range.getNumColumns();
  for(var i=0;i<rangenr;i++){
    for(var j=0;j<rangenc;j++){
    var sBD = range.offset(i,j).getBorder();
if(sBD!==null){
      var sBDR = sBD.getRight().getBorderStyle();
      if(sBDR!==null){
        var sBDRs = sBDR.toString();
       if(sBDRs!==null){ 
  destination.offset(i,j,1,1).setBorder(null,null,null,true,false,false,SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.sBDRs)}
      console.log(SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.sBDRs);}
      }
      }

For the console.log(SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.sBDR) and console.log(SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.sBDRs) they both are reading as undefined. Does anyone know what formatting needs to be change from the sBDR in this example for it to work with SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle. to set the border of the destination cell?
Range is a named range from another sheet and destination is the range on the sheet that I will be setting this into.
To make this more clear I have created sheets to share as an example:
Source sheet (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1calbWQ3GNQMuShxI2tuqlt8yldHaBklkqpPJ1WOKvtY/edit?gid=0#gid=0)
Target sheet (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UJsbhTynho0H6moDspg4qQfdo_YMRkHaw0VGsdHdSpQ/edit?gid=0#gid=0)
I want to make this script a dynamic script that I can put into multiple situations to copy a named ranges borders from one sheet to another below is how he entire script would work. The merging format script is also on here. I did not mention it previously since this works great.


function copyandpaste(range,destination) {
var ranger=range.getRow()
  var rangec = range.getColumn()
  var rangenr = range.getNumRows();
  var rangenc = range.getNumColumns();
  var sMG = range.getMergedRanges();

  for(var k=0;k<sMG.length;k++){
    var rowNum = sMG[k].getRow();
    var colNum = sMG[k].getColumn();
    var numrow = sMG[k].getNumRows();
    var numcol = sMG[k].getNumColumns();
    destination.offset(rowNum-ranger,colNum-rangec,numrow,numcol).merge(); 

    }

  for(var i=0;i<rangenr;i++){
    for(var j=0;j<rangenc;j++){
      var targetl = destination.offset(i,j,1,1).getA1Notation();
      var sBD = range.offset(i,j,1,1).getBorder();
      if(sBD!==null){
      var sBDL = sBD.getLeft().getBorderStyle();
      if(sBDL!==null){
        var sBDLs=sBDL.toString()
      if(sBDLs=="SOLID"){
        destination.offset(i,j,1,1).setBorder(null,true,null,null,false,false,'black',SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID)}
      if(sBDLs=="DOTTED"){
        destination.offset(i,j,1,1).setBorder(null,true,null,null,false,false,'black',SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.DOTTED)}
      if(sBDLs=="DASHED"){
        destination.offset(i,j,1,1).setBorder(null,true,null,null,false,false,'black',SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.DASHED)}
      if(sBDLs=="SOLID_MEDIUM"){
        destination.offset(i,j,1,1).setBorder(null,true,null,null,false,false,'black',SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_MEDIUM)}
      if(sBDLs=="SOLID_THICK"){
        destination.offset(i,j,1,1).setBorder(null,true,null,null,false,false,'black',SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_THICK)}
      if(sBDLs=="DOUBLE"){
        destination.offset(i,j,1,1).setBorder(null,true,null,null,false,false,'black',SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.DOUBLE)}
        }
      }
      if(sBD!==null){
      var sBDR = sBD.getRight().getBorderStyle();
      if(sBDR!==null){
      var sBDRs=sBDR.toString()
      if(sBDRs=="SOLID"){
        destination.offset(i,j,1,1).setBorder(null,null,null,true,false,false,'black',SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID)}
      if(sBDRs=="DOTTED"){
        destination.offset(i,j,1,1).setBorder(null,null,null,true,false,false,'black',SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.DOTTED)}
      if(sBDRs=="DASHED"){
        destination.offset(i,j,1,1).setBorder(null,null,null,true,false,false,'black',SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.DASHED)}
      if(sBDRs=="SOLID_MEDIUM"){
        destination.offset(i,j,1,1).setBorder(null,null,null,true,false,false,'black',SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_MEDIUM)}
      if(sBDRs=="SOLID_THICK"){console.log(targetl)
        destination.offset(i,j,1,1).setBorder(null,null,null,true,false,false,'black',SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_THICK)}
      if(sBDRs=="DOUBLE"){
        destination.offset(i,j,1,1).setBorder(null,null,null,true,false,false,'black',SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.DOUBLE)}
      }
     }
      if(sBD!==null){
      var sBDT = sBD.getTop().getBorderStyle();
      if(sBDT!==null){;
      var sBDTs=sBDT.toString()
      if(sBDTs=="SOLID"){
        destination.offset(i,j,1,1).setBorder(true,null,null,null,false,false,'black',SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID)}
      if(sBDTs=="DOTTED"){
        destination.offset(i,j,1,1).setBorder(true,null,null,null,false,false,'black',SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.DOTTED)}
      if(sBDTs=="DASHED"){
        destination.offset(i,j,1,1).setBorder(true,null,null,null,false,false,'black',SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.DASHED)}
      if(sBDTs=="SOLID_MEDIUM"){
        destination.offset(i,j,1,1).setBorder(true,null,null,null,false,false,'black',SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_MEDIUM)}
      if(sBDTs=="SOLID_THICK"){
        destination.offset(i,j,1,1).setBorder(true,null,null,null,false,false,'black',SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_THICK)}
      if(sBDTs=="DOUBLE"){
        
        destination.offset(i,j,1,1).setBorder(true,null,null,null,false,false,'black',SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.DOUBLE)}
        }
        }
      if(sBD!==null){
      var sBDB = sBD.getBottom().getBorderStyle();
      if(sBDB!==null){;
       var sBDBs=sBDB.toString()
      if(sBDBs=="SOLID"){
        destination.offset(i,j,1,1).setBorder(null,null,true,null,false,false,'black',SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID)}
      if(sBDBs=="DOTTED"){
        destination.offset(i,j,1,1).setBorder(null,null,true,null,false,false,'black',SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.DOTTED)}
      if(sBDBs=="DASHED"){
        destination.offset(i,j,1,1).setBorder(null,null,true,null,false,false,'black',SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.DASHED)}
      if(sBDBs=="SOLID_MEDIUM"){
        destination.offset(i,j,1,1).setBorder(null,null,true,null,false,false,'black',SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_MEDIUM)}
      if(sBDBs=="SOLID_THICK"){
        destination.offset(i,j,1,1).setBorder(null,null,true,null,false,false,'black',SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_THICK)}
      if(sBDBs=="DOUBLE"){
        destination.offset(i,j,1,1).setBorder(null,null,true,null,false,false,'black',SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.DOUBLE)}
        }
    }
    }}
     
      for(var k=0;k<sMG.length;k++){
    var rowNum = sMG[k].getRow();
    var colNum = sMG[k].getColumn();
    var numrow = sMG[k].getNumRows();
    var numcol = sMG[k].getNumColumns();
         var sBD = range.offset(rowNum-ranger,colNum-rangec,numrow,numcol).getBorder();
      if(sBD!==null){
      var sBDL = sBD.getLeft().getBorderStyle();
      if(sBDL!==null){
        var sBDLs=sBDL.toString()
      if(sBDLs=="SOLID"){
        destination.offset(rowNum-ranger,colNum-rangec,numrow,numcol).setBorder(null,true,null,null,false,false,'black',SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID)}
      if(sBDLs=="DOTTED"){
        destination.offset(rowNum-ranger,colNum-rangec,numrow,numcol).setBorder(null,true,null,null,false,false,'black',SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.DOTTED)}
      if(sBDLs=="DASHED"){
        destination.offset(rowNum-ranger,colNum-rangec,numrow,numcol).setBorder(null,true,null,null,false,false,'black',SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.DASHED)}
      if(sBDLs=="SOLID_MEDIUM"){
        destination.offset(rowNum-ranger,colNum-rangec,numrow,numcol).setBorder(null,true,null,null,false,false,'black',SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_MEDIUM)}
      if(sBDLs=="SOLID_THICK"){
        destination.offset(rowNum-ranger,colNum-rangec,numrow,numcol).setBorder(null,true,null,null,false,false,'black',SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_THICK)}
      if(sBDLs=="DOUBLE"){
        destination.offset(rowNum-ranger,colNum-rangec,numrow,numcol).setBorder(null,true,null,null,false,false,'black',SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.DOUBLE)}
        }
      }
      if(sBD!==null){
      var sBDR = sBD.getRight().getBorderStyle();
      if(sBDR!==null){
      var sBDRs=sBDR.toString()
      if(sBDRs=="SOLID"){
        destination.offset(rowNum-ranger,colNum-rangec,numrow,numcol).setBorder(null,null,null,true,false,false,'black',SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID)}
      if(sBDRs=="DOTTED"){
        destination.offset(rowNum-ranger,colNum-rangec,numrow,numcol).setBorder(null,null,null,true,false,false,'black',SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.DOTTED)}
      if(sBDRs=="DASHED"){
        destination.offset(rowNum-ranger,colNum-rangec,numrow,numcol).setBorder(null,null,null,true,false,false,'black',SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.DASHED)}
      if(sBDRs=="SOLID_MEDIUM"){
        destination.offset(rowNum-ranger,colNum-rangec,numrow,numcol).setBorder(null,null,null,true,false,false,'black',SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_MEDIUM)}
      if(sBDRs=="SOLID_THICK"){
        destination.offset(rowNum-ranger,colNum-rangec,numrow,numcol).setBorder(null,null,null,true,false,false,'black',SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_THICK)}
      if(sBDRs=="DOUBLE"){
        destination.offset(rowNum-ranger,colNum-rangec,numrow,numcol).setBorder(null,null,null,true,false,false,'black',SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.DOUBLE)}
      }
     }
      if(sBD!==null){
      var sBDT = sBD.getTop().getBorderStyle();
      if(sBDT!==null){;
      var sBDTs=sBDT.toString()
      if(sBDTs=="SOLID"){
        destination.offset(rowNum-ranger,colNum-rangec,numrow,numcol).setBorder(true,null,null,null,false,false,'black',SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID)}
      if(sBDTs=="DOTTED"){
        destination.offset(rowNum-ranger,colNum-rangec,numrow,numcol).setBorder(true,null,null,null,false,false,'black',SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.DOTTED)}
      if(sBDTs=="DASHED"){
        destination.offset(rowNum-ranger,colNum-rangec,numrow,numcol).setBorder(true,null,null,null,false,false,'black',SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.DASHED)}
      if(sBDTs=="SOLID_MEDIUM"){
        destination.offset(rowNum-ranger,colNum-rangec,numrow,numcol).setBorder(true,null,null,null,false,false,'black',SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_MEDIUM)}
      if(sBDTs=="SOLID_THICK"){
        destination.offset(rowNum-ranger,colNum-rangec,numrow,numcol).setBorder(true,null,null,null,false,false,'black',SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_THICK)}
      if(sBDTs=="DOUBLE"){
        destination.offset(rowNum-ranger,colNum-rangec,numrow,numcol).setBorder(true,null,null,null,false,false,'black',SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.DOUBLE)}
        }
        }
      if(sBD!==null){
      var sBDB = sBD.getBottom().getBorderStyle();
      if(sBDB!==null){;
       var sBDBs=sBDB.toString()
      if(sBDBs=="SOLID"){
        destination.offset(rowNum-ranger,colNum-rangec,numrow,numcol).setBorder(null,null,true,null,false,false,'black',SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID)}
      if(sBDBs=="DOTTED"){
        destination.offset(rowNum-ranger,colNum-rangec,numrow,numcol).setBorder(null,null,true,null,false,false,'black',SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.DOTTED)}
      if(sBDBs=="DASHED"){
        destination.offset(rowNum-ranger,colNum-rangec,numrow,numcol).setBorder(null,null,true,null,false,false,'black',SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.DASHED)}
      if(sBDBs=="SOLID_MEDIUM"){
        destination.offset(rowNum-ranger,colNum-rangec,numrow,numcol).setBorder(null,null,true,null,false,false,'black',SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_MEDIUM)}
      if(sBDBs=="SOLID_THICK"){
        destination.offset(rowNum-ranger,colNum-rangec,numrow,numcol).setBorder(null,null,true,null,false,false,'black',SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_THICK)}
      if(sBDBs=="DOUBLE"){
        destination.offset(rowNum-ranger,colNum-rangec,numrow,numcol).setBorder(null,null,true,null,false,false,'black',SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.DOUBLE)}
        }
      }
      }
}


function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var target = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1calbWQ3GNQMuShxI2tuqlt8yldHaBklkqpPJ1WOKvtY/edit?gid=0#gid=0");
  var source1range = source.getRangeByName("Source1");
  var target1destination = target.getRange("B6:Q13");
  copyandpaste(source1range,target1destination);
   var source2range = source.getRangeByName("Source2");
  var target2destination = target.getRange("B15:Y32");
  copyandpaste(source2range,target2destination);
  var source3range = source.getRangeByName("Source3");
  var target3destination = target.getRange("B34:Y73");
  copyandpaste(source3range,target3destination);

}



This is all that I have figured out so far but there must be an easier way to accomplish this and create it as a dynamic script to be used in multiple places.

Can you specify the parameters input? range, destination

Please make a minimal reproducible example that can be copy/paste/run without changes to illustrate the issue.

This question is similar to: What is an alternative function for getBorderlines in Google App scripts?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You want to set the right border for a cell based on the right border of another cell.
The script is failing (or will fail) for several reasons:

getBorder() (sBD) can have a value of "null" if one or more borders aren't set and this will halt the script

var sBD = targetRange.getBorder()?? "No Border" is a workaround for a null value (using the Javascript Nullish coalescing operator (??) to set a default value if sBD evaluates to null


the syntax of setBorder doc ref includes a "color"

setBorder(top, left, bottom, right, vertical, horizontal, color, style)


the style argument in setBorder is a BorderStyle and must be in the form parent class, name, and property For example, SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.DOTTED

the BorderStyle does not appear to accept a variable as the property. For example SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.sBDR will create a "solid" border regardless of the value of "sBDR"
this means that a style needs to be assigned for each possible value of "sBDR". The following script uses a series of "if/else" statements.



The following script is based on the OP's script but the range and destination are declared within the function.

function borderCopy() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1")
  var range = sheet.getRange("A2:B8")
  var destination = sheet.getRange("F10")
  
  // get the top left cell in the range
  var rangeCell = sheet.getRange(range.getRow(),range.getColumn())
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: the starting cell = "+rangeCell.getA1Notation())
  
  var rangenr = range.getNumRows();
  var rangenc = range.getNumColumns();
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: range rows = "+rangenr+", range columns = "+rangenc)

  // Loop through the range
  for(var i=0;i<rangenr;i++){
    for(var j=0;j<rangenc;j++){
      var targetRange = rangeCell.offset(i,j)
      var destinationRange = destination.offset(i,j)
      // Logger.log("DEBUG: targetRange = "+targetRange.getA1Notation()+", destinationRange = "+destinationRange.getA1Notation())
      
      // get the border for the target cell
      // if result is null, then assign default value
      var sBD = targetRange.getBorder()?? "No Border"
      // test for null/default value and skip to next cell
      if (sBD == "No Border"){
        // do nothing, skip to next cell
        Logger.log("DEBUG: Border for "+destinationRange.getA1Notation()+" was not set")
        continue
      }

      // get the right border attributes
      var sBDR = sBD.getRight().getBorderStyle()
      // set the style based on the Border Style
      if (sBDR == "DOTTED") {
        var style = SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.DOTTED
      } else if (sBDR == "DASHED") {
        var style = SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.DASHED
      } else if (sBDR == "SOLID") {
        var style = SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID
      }  else if (sBDR == "SOLID_MEDIUM") {
        var style = SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_MEDIUM
      }  else if (sBDR == "SOLID_THICK") {
        var style = SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_THICK
      } else if (sBDR == "DOUBLE") {
        var style = SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.DOUBLE
      } 
      //Logger.log("DEBUG: i="+i+", j="+j+", target Cell = "+targetRange.getA1Notation()+", destination Cell = "+destinationRange.getA1Notation()+" Right = "+style)
      
      // update the right border in the destination.
      destinationRange.setBorder(null, null, null,   true,  false,    false,      "red", style)
      Logger.log("DEBUG: set right Border for "+destinationRange.getA1Notation()+" with "+sBDR)
    }
  }
}


SAMPLE - Before


SAMPLE - After



That you Tedinoz! You are correct, that was dumb of me. I was just missing the color parameter for this to work. Thank you for the quick fix.

If this answers your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon) and upvote the answer.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.

I have run into two issues with this. The first is that this does not work over merged rows. I fixed this by using .getMergedRanges() and just rerunning the the same script over the merged rows a second time. The second issue I ran into is that the borders that are made are only SOLID and not the targetRange BorderStyle (DASHED, SOLID_MEDIUM, ECT.)  Do you know why this is?

The first is that this does not work over merged rows. Merged rows aren't mentioned in the question or in the sample script. The very first comment was Can you specify the parameters input? range, destination. I'm pleased that you have a solution but perhaps it could be better. Please provide details and we'll see whether it can be answered here or in another question.

The second issue I ran into is that the borders that are made are only SOLID I tested with "solid" borders so didn't notice this at the time. I've now revised the script as well as the introduction. Note: 1) var sBD = targetRange.getBorder() can yield null but it also stops the script. 2) the BorderStyle doesn't accept a variable; it needs to be spelled out in full.

merged rows or merged cells. Please clarify. In any event, I think that you might find that the revised script handled merged cells.

Yes this answers all my questions. thank you very much for all of the help

Alternative solution using copyFormatToRange()
Here's an alternative solution for setBorderStyle() where it will copy the border and its border style.
Code:
function test1() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var source = ss.getSheets()[0]; //source sheet (sheet1)
  var destination = ss.getSheets()[1]; //  destination sheet (sheet2)
  var range = source.getRange("A1:B6"); // Range of the format you want to copy
  range.copyFormatToRange(destination, 3, 3, 1, 6);
  console.log(range.getA1Notation());
}

Output:

For Visual output only.



Note: The method copyFormatToRange copies the formatting only.

Reference:

copyFormatToRange


Thank you, Jats PPG. Sorry I should have mentioned this in the original post. Yes I would very much like to use this method. Unfortunately, I am going from one spreadsheet to another spreadsheet and this function is only allowed if your are copying a range within the same spreadsheet.

I understand. I just assumed that you are just copying from one sheet tab to another.

I just assumed that you are just copying from one sheet tab to another. Hmm. That's what I assumed as well. I guess I got away with it be declaring the target and source within the function. @Paperless, you never did explain how "you specify the parameters input? range, destination"
